# Question about DB access control for concurrency using 'Typeorm'

Tags: typescript, locking, typeorm

While creating TypeScript(NestJS) applications, I encountered a problem.
The application I'm creating should leverage the database, so I'm using 'Typeorm'.
According to the logic, **to maintain consistency**, I'd like to use the **'lock mechanism'** provided by 'Typeorm'.
But it doesn't work well so I ask for help like this.
How can I solve this? I'll be grateful for any advice.(It would be better if there was an example.)

Comment: Can you please explain what's your problem. I really can't understand what's wrong. Thanks. PS: For lock mechanism you refer to transactions?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63296041/how-to-pessimistic-locking)
here is my problem, Thanks.

Comment: You must open a transaction before any critical operation and use the entity manager provided. See docs [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/transactions.md).